# Is this linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I'm not sure how to distinguish linear from nonlinear regression. Linear regression should be linear in the parameters. I have the doubt if the following equation can be considered as a linear regression function: $y=ax_1x_2+bx_2$, with $a$, $b$ the parameters, $x_1$, $x_2$ the independent variables and $y$ the dependent variable.

Comment: that's linear if $a x_1 x_2$  is viewed as the interaction term but AFAIK, you should include all of the linear terms involved in the interaction so $c x_1$ should be included also.

Comment: Define $x_3=x_1x_2$ to make it clear